# Multiple git packfiles

Tags: git

I would like to know if it is possible to have more than one pack file (and index) for the same repository. Some kind of accumulative pack file that just contains the differences since the last push for instance.

I'm seeing this in a custom implementation using git and I would like to know if it is something natural to git.

Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [phd answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50373879/1256452), Git *will* read multiple pack files (and pack index files).  Note, however, that each pack file is required to be fully self-contained: deltified object's bases for an object inside the pack must also be inside that same pack.  (For instance if the deltified representation of object `0123...` says *start with `4567...` and make these changes*, object `4567...` must be in the *same* pack file.)  This means that many small packs are likely to use more space than fewer larger packs.

*Differences since the last push* actually occur rather naturally, because `git push` over smart protocols work by having the two Gits converse to see which objects to transfer.  The sender then sends a *thin pack*, which deliberately violates the above rule—it will contain only the deltified objects and not their bases—which the receiver must "fatten" using `git index-pack --fix-thin`.  If the receiver does that, and leaves the fattened, no-longer-thin pack in place, the receiver now has N+1 packs where the receiver used to have N packs.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for.
Once I have several deltified objects do you know how to join all of them in a single one I can read and get the full repository?

Comment: @m_jero: `git repack` will do that. There's a bunch of worthwhile housekeeping to run before `git repack`, and all of that is collected into `git gc` (which you can run yourself, or just let `git gc --auto` eventually choose to do it when Git's heuristics decide that there are "too many" scattered packs or loose objects or whatever else is appropriate to call for gc-ing). A number of user-facing commands run `git gc --auto` automatically.

Comment: My scenario is a little bit different.
I need to reconstruct a new git repository with the help of the refs file and the multiple delta pack files, no previous git repository to use as a base.
Do you know if it is possible?

Comment: If you have only the fattened previously-thin packs, you may be missing many objects. You can find out: create a `.git` directory with the usual subdirectories, write the references and packs into their normal locations, create a `HEAD` file in its normal location, index the packs if necessary, and then run `git fsck`.

Comment: If I clone the repository and verify the single pack file it has, I get this output:
hash1 commit 260 169 12
hash2 tree   87 95 181
hash3 commit 209 135 276
hash4 blob   429 312 411
hash5 blob   6 15 723
hash6 tree   41 51 738
non delta: 6 objects

Then, if I do the same with the other 2 packs, I get:
hash3 commit 209 222 12
hash6 tree   41 54 234
hash4 blob   429 442 288
non delta: 3 objects
**********
hash1 commit 260 273 12
hash2 tree   87 100 285
hash5 blob   6 18 385
non delta: 3 objects

I think this information should be enough for restoring the repository, isn't it?

Comment: In that particular case, it does seem to be everything you need. The problem will occur if (not *when* but *if*) an ex-thin-pack has, say, 100 out of 1000 objects, and the second ex-thin-pack has 200 out of 1000 objects, with the remaining 700 (or more if there is overlap in the two ex-thin packs) found only in the original pack. There's no way to find out other than to read through all the objects that indirect to more objects (annotated tags, commits, and trees) and build the graph.

Answer (score 2):

You can limit packfiles by size setting [pack.packSizeLimit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-packpackSizeLimit). Reaching this limit git creates multiple packfiles.

Comment: Is there a package limit without this setting?

Comment: @Whu_Kingsun [`git-repack --max-pack-size=<n>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack#Documentation/git-repack.txt---max-pack-sizeltngt)